# When running AWS batch job, receive a Received Resourceinitializationerror: failed to validate logger args: no such host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I am running an AWS batch job, and it fails to start, with this Status reason:

> Resourceinitializationerror: failed to validate logger args: create stream has been retried 7 times: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://logs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp: lookup logs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com on 172.31.0.2:53: no such host : exit status 1

The job runs in a compute environment on `eu-central-1` that uses a VPC, and that VPC has an endpoint to `com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.logs`

What can be done to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found what the problem was - I forgot to associate the subnet to the endpoint to `com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.logs`

Comment: Thanks for replying to your own question! This helped me!